# Upload Csv com php erro: Undefined offset:

Tags: php

bom dia.
estou fazendo upload de csv com php, o mesmo faz o processamento mas dá o seguinte erro: " Undefined offset:" não consigo identificar este erro e tratar... Help me!..

Comment: Coloque o seu código para podermos ajudar

Comment: Segue o Código:

Comment: Primeira Parte: $arrFileName = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
  if ($arrFileName[0] = 'csv') {
   $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
   fgetcsv($handle);

Comment: segunda Parte: while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

    $WORKORDERUID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[0]);

Comment: a variavel $data[0] vai até a variavel $data[19]

Comment: dai vem a query de import, Select into....

Comment: Você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/333396/edit) sua pergunta e adicionar o código lá, também é bom [formatar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ele, assim fica mais legível. Depois de fazer pode apagar os comentários :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro de "**Undefined offset**" geralmente acontece quando você esta tentando fazer alguma operação com o valor inexistente de um array.

Em arquivos CSV (ou excel) algumas vezes vem linhas e colunas vazias, que ele entende como sendo parte to arquivo (mesmo não tendo valor nenhum). Por isso antes de realizar **explodes**, ou outras operações, é sempre bom testar se o valor do array realmente existe:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) { [...] }
```